# Computing $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n}}{n^{2}+k^2}$ for $k\in N.$

Tags: trigonometry, power-series, hypergeometric-function

I am now going to share a solution on
$$S=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n}}{n^{2}+k^2}$$ using the Theorem
$\displaystyle \pi \csc (\pi z)=\lim _{N \rightarrow \infty} \sum_{n=-N}^{N} \frac{(-1)^{k}}{k+z},\tag*{(*)} \textrm{  where } z \not \in Z. $

We first split the series into 2 by partial fractions.

$\displaystyle \begin{aligned}S &=-\frac{1}{2 ki } \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\left(\frac{(-1)^{n}}{n+ki}-\frac{(-1)^{n}}{n-ki}\right) \\&=-\frac{1}{2 ki}\left(\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n}}{n+ki}-\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n}}{n-ki}\right) \end{aligned}\tag*{} $

Re-indexing n to convert $S$ back to a single series yields

$\displaystyle \begin{aligned}S&=-\frac{1}{2 ki}\left(\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n}}{n+ki}+\sum_{n=-1}^{-\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n}}{n+ki}+\frac{1}{ki} \right) \\&=-\frac{1}{2 ki}\left(\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n}}{n+ki}+\frac{1}{ki}\right)\end{aligned}\tag*{} $
Applying the Theorem (*) gives
$\displaystyle \begin{aligned}S &=-\frac{1}{2 ki}\left(\pi \csc (k\pi i)+\frac{1}{ki}\right) \\&=-\frac{1}{2 ki}\left(-i \pi \operatorname{csch}(k\pi)+\frac{1}{ki}\right)\\&=\frac{1}{2k}\left(\pi  \operatorname{csch} (k\pi)+\frac{1}{2k} \right)\\& \left(\textrm{ OR }  \frac{1}{4k^2}+\frac{\pi}{k(e^{\pi}-e^{-\pi})}\right)\end{aligned}\tag*{} $

**Your comments and alternative methods are highly appreciated.**

Comment: FYI, using an [Approach0 search](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24%5Csum_%7Bn%3D0%7D%5E%7B%5Cinfty%7D%5Cfrac%7B(-1)%5E%7Bn%7D%7D%7Bn%5E%7B2%7D%2Bk%5E2%7D%24&p=1), there's [Evaluate the Series in Closed Form: $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n}{n^2+a^2}$](/q/334550), the closely related [Show $\frac{\pi}{\alpha \sinh (\pi \alpha)} = \sum_{n= -\infty}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{\alpha^2 + n^2}$](/q/2148282) & [A (basic?) contour integration problem](/q/1315970), and the related [Using Fourier Series to find the sum of a numerical series](/q/1712431).

Comment: @John-omielan, thank you for your valuable links by which I can search before asking questions in MSE.

Answer (score 1):

After the partial fraction, computing the sums in terms of the polygamma function, converting to generalized harmonic numbers give
$$S_p=\sum_{n=0}^{p} \frac{(-1)^{n}}{n^{2}+k^2}=\frac{1+\pi  k \coth (\pi  k)-i k \left(H_{p-i k}-H_{p+i k}\right)}{2 k^2}$$ Using the asymptotics
$$S_p=\frac{1+\pi  k \coth (\pi  k)}{2 k^2}-\frac{1}{p}+\frac{1}{2
   p^2}+\frac{2 k^2-1}{6 p^3}+O\left(\frac{1}{p^4}\right)$$